# What is the argument `serving_input_fn` of method `export_savedmodel`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, inference

I am trying to train a Char RNN and **export/save the model** after training, so that I can use it at inference. Here's the model:

```
def char_rnn_model(features, target):
    """Character level recurrent neural network model to predict classes."""
    target = tf.one_hot(target, 15, 1, 0)
    #byte_list = tf.one_hot(features, 256, 1, 0)
    byte_list = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(features, 256, 1, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    byte_list = tf.unstack(byte_list, axis=1)

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_SIZE)
    _, encoding = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, byte_list, dtype=tf.float32)


    logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(encoding, 15, activation_fn=None)
    #loss = tf.contrib.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, target)
    loss = tf.contrib.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits=logits, onehot_labels=target)

    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
      loss,
      tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
      optimizer='Adam',
      learning_rate=0.001)

    return ({
      'class': tf.argmax(logits, 1),
      'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    }, loss, train_op)
```

and the training part:

```
# train
model_dir = "model"
classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=char_rnn_model,model_dir=model_dir)
count=0
n_epoch = 20
while count<n_epoch:
        print("\nEPOCH " + str(count))
        classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, steps=1000,batch_size=10)
        y_predicted = [
              p['class'] for p in classifier.predict(
              x_test, as_iterable=True,batch_size=10)
        ]
        score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted)
        print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(score))
        count+=1
```

(`x_train` is a uint8 array of shape (16639, 100))

[Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator?authuser=0&hl=ro) documentation tells about the method `export_savedmodel` that seems to do what I want. But I don't understand the second argument `serving_input_fn`.  What should it be ? `classifier.export_savedmodel(output_dir, ???)`

I am using Tensorflow 1.8.0 and python 2.7.14.

This is in relation with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140429/inference-with-tensorflow-checkpoints).

**============
EDIT
============**

I tried both solutions suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330841/how-to-save-and-restore-a-tf-estimator-estimator-model-with-export-savedmodel):

1. Redefine an estimator with argument `model_dir` having the same value than the one used during training with hope that the model will be automatically restored with the optimized weights :

   `with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file) 
        new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir))
        classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=char_rnn_model,model_dir=model_dir)
        new_input = ['Some sequence of characters']
        char_processor = learn.preprocessing.ByteProcessor(100)
        new_input_processed = np.array(list(char_processor.transform(new_input)))
        print('new_input_processed: ', new_input_processed)
        p = classifier.predict(new_input_processed, as_iterable=True)
        predicted_class = p['class'] 
        print('predicted_class: ', predicted_class)`

but I get the following error

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from section_header_rnn/section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3/model.ckpt-512000
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_task_type': None, '_train_distribute': None, '_is_chief': True, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f6794bc3050>, '_model_dir': 'section_header_rnn/section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3', '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_session_config': None, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_environment': 'local', '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_task_id': 0, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1.0
}
, '_evaluation_master': '', '_master': ''}
('new_input_processed: ', array([[ 83, 111, 109, 101,  32, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110,  99, 101,
         32, 111, 102,  32,  99, 104,  97, 114,  97,  99, 116, 101, 114,
        115,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e069212a21a0> in <module>()
     11     new_input_processed = np.array(list(char_processor.transform(new_input)))
     12     print('new_input_processed: ', new_input_processed)
---> 13     p = classifier.predict(new_input_processed, as_iterable=True)
     14     predicted_class = p['class']
     15     print('predicted_class: ', predicted_class)

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.pyc in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    430                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    431                 instructions)
--> 432       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    433     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(func, new_func, 'deprecated',
    434                                        _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in predict(self, x, input_fn, batch_size, outputs, as_iterable, iterate_batches)
    668         outputs=outputs,
    669         as_iterable=as_iterable,
--> 670         iterate_batches=iterate_batches)
    671 
    672   def get_variable_value(self, name):

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in _infer_model(self, input_fn, feed_fn, outputs, as_iterable, iterate_batches)
    966       training_util.create_global_step(g)
    967       features = self._get_features_from_input_fn(input_fn)
--> 968       infer_ops = self._get_predict_ops(features)
    969       predictions = self._filter_predictions(infer_ops.predictions, outputs)
    970       mon_sess = monitored_session.MonitoredSession(

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in _get_predict_ops(self, features)
   1312     labels = tensor_signature.create_placeholders_from_signatures(
   1313         self._labels_info)
-> 1314     return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.INFER)
   1315 
   1316   def export_savedmodel(self,

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, metrics, config)
   1225     if 'model_dir' in model_fn_args:
   1226       kwargs['model_dir'] = self.model_dir
-> 1227     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
   1228 
   1229     if isinstance(model_fn_results, model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps):

<ipython-input-10-55c752822baa> in char_rnn_model(features, target)
      1 def char_rnn_model(features, target):
      2     """Character level recurrent neural network model to predict classes."""
----> 3     target = tf.one_hot(target, 15, 1, 0)
      4     #byte_list = tf.one_hot(features, 256, 1, 0)
      5     byte_list = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(features, 256, 1, 0), dtype=tf.float32)

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.pyc in one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis, dtype, name)
   2500 
   2501     return gen_array_ops.one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis,
-> 2502                                  name)
   2503 
   2504 

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.pyc in one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis, name)
   4364     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
   4365         "OneHot", indices=indices, depth=depth, on_value=on_value,
-> 4366         off_value=off_value, axis=axis, name=name)
   4367     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   4368     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.pyc in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    526               raise ValueError(
    527                   "Tried to convert '%s' to a tensor and failed. Error: %s" %
--> 528                   (input_name, err))
    529             prefix = ("Input '%s' of '%s' Op has type %s that does not match" %
    530                       (input_name, op_type_name, observed))

ValueError: Tried to convert 'indices' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

2. The second solution is to use the function `serving_input_fn` defined in the answer to [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330841/how-to-save-and-restore-a-tf-estimator-estimator-model-with-export-savedmodel):

   `def serving_input_fn():`

   ```
   inputs = {'features': tf.placeholder(tf.uint8)}
   return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)
   ```

   `def train_test(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, max_depth):`

   ```
   # Build model
   model_dir = "model_dir"

   classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=char_rnn_model,model_dir=model_dir)

   count=0
   while count<1 #n_epoch:
       print("\nEPOCH " + str(count))
       classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, steps=1000,batch_size=10)
       y_predicted = [
             p['class'] for p in classifier.predict(
             x_test, as_iterable=True,batch_size=10)
       ]
       score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted)
       print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(score))
       count+=1

   print("\n More details:")
   predicted = [
         p['class'] for p in classifier.predict(
         x_test, as_iterable=True,batch_size=10)
   ]
   print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))

   export_dir = model_dir + "_EXPORT"
   classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir, serving_input_fn)

   return f1_score
   ```

But again I obtain an error:

```
++++++++++
RUN 0
++++++++++
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_task_type': None, '_train_distribute': None, '_is_chief': True, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f7af77a40d0>, '_model_dir': 'section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3', '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_session_config': None, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_environment': 'local', '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_task_id': 0, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1.0
}
, '_evaluation_master': '', '_master': ''}

EPOCH 0
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3/model.ckpt-516000
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 516001 into section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 4.84674e-05, step = 516001
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 16.343
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.6498e-05, step = 516101 (6.118 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 50.2856
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 9.97774e-06, step = 516201 (1.989 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 51.1929
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 7.67226e-05, step = 516301 (1.953 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 52.1178
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 4.43674e-05, step = 516401 (1.919 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 51.4657
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.10982e-05, step = 516501 (1.943 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 51.517
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 2.57473e-05, step = 516601 (1.941 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 50.8899
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.01228e-05, step = 516701 (1.965 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 50.3907
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.85045e-06, step = 516801 (1.985 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 51.3651
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.09075e-05, step = 516901 (1.947 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 517000 into section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 1.77617e-05.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3/model.ckpt-517000
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
Accuracy: 0.980756

 More details:
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from section_header_text_only_char_rnn_max_depth=3/model.ckpt-517000
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.99      0.99      0.99      6139
          1       0.94      0.95      0.94      1292

avg / total       0.98      0.98      0.98      7431

Confusion Matrix
[[6066   73]
 [  70 1222]]
Done

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-d7817a1be627> in <module>()
     65     print("RUN " + str(i_run))
     66     print("++++++++++")
---> 67     f1 = train_test(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, max_depth)
     68     f1s.append(f1)
     69 print("\n\n")

<ipython-input-90-d7817a1be627> in train_test(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, max_depth)
     53     # export inference graph
     54     export_dir = model_dir + "_EXPORT"
---> 55     classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir, serving_input_fn)
     56 
     57     return f1_score

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in export_savedmodel(self, export_dir_base, serving_input_fn, default_output_alternative_key, assets_extra, as_text, checkpoint_path, graph_rewrite_specs, strip_default_attrs)
   1386       input_ops = serving_input_fn()
   1387       input_alternatives, features = (
-> 1388           saved_model_export_utils.get_input_alternatives(input_ops))
   1389 
   1390       # TODO(b/34388557) This is a stopgap, pending recording model provenance.

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.pyc in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    248               'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    249               instructions)
--> 250       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    251     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(
    252         func, new_func, 'deprecated',

/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/utils/saved_model_export_utils.pyc in get_input_alternatives(input_ops)
    171     input_alternatives[DEFAULT_INPUT_ALTERNATIVE_KEY] = default_inputs
    172   else:
--> 173     features, unused_labels = input_ops
    174 
    175   if not features:

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if there is the `model.save` method as the Tensorflow documentation says.
Otherwise you can just save the weights and then reload them into a default model.
You can write:

```
# Save the weights
model.save_weights('./checkpoints/my_checkpoint')

# Create a new model instance
model = create_model()

# Restore the weights
model.load_weights('./checkpoints/my_checkpoint')
```

---

### EDIT

In order to create a model very fast you can use the `Sequential` class that lets you save the model or the weights 
(see here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#save).

A Sequential object is basically a container that you populate using `add(...)`. Operations will be done sequentially through the layers tyou specified. See Keras documentation (a wrapper for tensorflow, it uses basically the same objects), or directly tnesorflow.

Here i show you simple model for text processing, that is composed into:

- Embedding layer (just a lookup table)
- Bidirectional LSTM layer
- Droput Layer
- Dense layer (dimension = 100)
- Dense layer (dimension = number of classes)

Note that you don't have to specify a cycle for running different epochs, you just put the parameter in the fit method.

```
#Create empty sequential
model = Sequential()

# Add the different layers
model.add(Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, weights=[embedding_matrix]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Compile configures the model for training
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit train data
history = model.fit(train_we, np.array(train_lab), validation_split=0.2, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

# Custom function to plot the loss graph
utils.plot_history(history)

# Make predictions: it return a vector of probability on the given classes
list_prediction_proba = model.predict(test_we)

# Find the most likely class
prediction = [np.where(probabilities == probabilities.max())[0].min() for probabilities in list_prediction_proba]
```

If you need more information try this:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. According to the documentation (linked in my post), there is no `save` method in the class `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`. 
Concerning your suggestion, what should `create_model()` be ? I have never created a model directly with tensorflow sorry ^^. Supposing I have managed to the model, there is no `save_weights()` `load_weights` methods in the class `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`.

Comment: I edited the answer, hope that is useful. I kindly ask you, if the answer is right, to mark it as correct, so i can gain a little bit of reputation =)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. However, I would like to use the exact same model than the one defined in my post (cf function `char_rnn_model`).
I added a +1 to your post, that must enhance a little bit your reputation

Comment: Ok thanks, what i syour goal? what are you trying to implement?

Comment: The goal is to be able to save the trained model in files and load them back in memory in order to do predictions on new inputs. For now, I see the two solutions added after my EDIT : 1/load the meta file, restore a tensorflow session, instantiate a new `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` model with the same `model_dir` than the one used for training and do prediction; when using this solution I have a `ValueError` (full error in my post) 2/use the `export_savedmodel` method; the problem with this is that I don't know how to define the argument `serving_input_fn` of `export_savedmodel`